# Run jarfile on ftp without downloading

Tags: java, linux, ftp, executable-jar

I have executable jar file which i have kept on my ftp.

I wanted to autoschedule it through  linux server - cronjob.

I given the command :

```
java -jar filepath.jar
```

But when call goes to that file, it always asks for download, and after getting downloaded, it does not run automatically.

I want it to run automatically on the same server on which it is present (on ftp).

which command i can use for it??

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You could put something like this in your crontab :

`ssh user@host 'java -jar filepath.jar'`

and previously exchanging public keys between client and server so you won't be asked for the password

Answer (score 1):

FTP is file transfer protocol. It cannot be used to execute programs. You have to use ssh, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use ssh to login into remote PC or server , 
That can be done using command "ssh username@IP Address of remote pc" on terminal.

By this way u can login in into remote pc and u will get the terminal of that PC inside your terminal.
Now u can browse the files in that PC and simply execute any file u want without downloading.